# gitlab-ce on openshift origin 3.7.0-alpha (fedora 26) fails to start

Tags: docker, openshift, gitlab

After following the below-linked directions on creating a gitlab instance using a self hosted  openshift origin 3.7.0-alpha on fedora 26, I'm getting this on the gitlab-ce pod. I've tried deleting and redeploying the pod, and my best google-fu, but still no luck figuring out what the problem is or how to further troubleshoot it.  I am able to successfully deploy jenkins using the default provided template.

Directions - https://about.gitlab.com/2016/06/28/get-started-with-openshift-origin-3-and-gitlab

```
Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!
Current version: gitlab-ce=10.0.3-ce.0

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
And restart this container to reload settings.
To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
  docker restart gitlab

Preparing services...
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 24: ulimit: pending signals: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 34: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system
Starting services...
Configuring GitLab package...
gitlab preinstall: 
gitlab preinstall: This node does not appear to be running a database
gitlab preinstall: Skipping version check, if you think this is an error exit now
gitlab preinstall: 
Configuring GitLab...


  * Moving existing certificates found in /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs

  * Symlinking existing certificates found in /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs
gitlab Reconfigured!
No currently installed postgresql in the omnibus instance found.

Checking for an omnibus managed postgresql:
Checking for an omnibus managed postgresql: NOT OK
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Raven 2.5.3 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/api_json.log <==
# Logfile created on 2017-10-09 23:38:01 +0000 by logger.rb/56438

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
# Logfile created on 2017-10-09 23:38:01 +0000 by logger.rb/56438

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-2017-10-09-23-37-45.log <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56712 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56713 @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56713 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56714 Permissions 0711 for '/etc/gitlab/ssh_host_ed25519_key' are too open.
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56714 It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56714 This private key will be ignored.
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56714 key_load_private: bad permissions
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56714 Could not load host key: /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_ed25519_key
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56714 Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
2017-10-09_23:37:01.56715 Server listening on :: port 22.

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log <==
# Logfile created on 2017-10-09 23:37:08 +0000 by logger.rb/56438

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2017-10-09_23:38:06.93916 starting new unicorn master

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
I, [2017-10-09T23:38:07.809445 #430]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stdout.log <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/current <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:38:36 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:38:45 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/access.log <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/error.log <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/logrotate/current <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:38:26.33324 2017/10/09 23:38:26 Starting gitlab-workhorse v3.0.0-20171005.085311
2017-10-09_23:38:26.33403 2017/10/09 23:38:26 keywatcher: starting process loop
2017-10-09_23:38:26.33406 2017/10/09 23:38:26 redis: dialing "tcp", "gitlab-ce-redis:6379"
2017-10-09_23:38:36.03269 2017/10/09 23:38:36 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory
2017-10-09_23:38:36.04736 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:38:35.992527646 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.040289
2017-10-09_23:38:40.94743 2017/10/09 23:38:40 Starting gitlab-workhorse v3.0.0-20171005.085311
2017-10-09_23:38:40.94833 2017/10/09 23:38:40 keywatcher: starting process loop
2017-10-09_23:38:40.94835 2017/10/09 23:38:40 redis: dialing "tcp", "gitlab-ce-redis:6379"
2017-10-09_23:38:45.98639 2017/10/09 23:38:45 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory
2017-10-09_23:38:45.98650 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:38:45.985618433 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.000839

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitaly/current <==
2017-10-09_23:38:19.05998 time="2017-10-09T23:38:19Z" level=info msg="Starting Gitaly" version="Gitaly, version 0.38.0, built 20171005.085339
2017-10-09_23:38:19.06008 " 
2017-10-09_23:38:20.85694 time="2017-10-09T23:38:20Z" level=warning msg="git path not configured. Using default path resolution" resolvedPath="/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git" 
2017-10-09_23:38:20.85696 time="2017-10-09T23:38:20Z" level=info msg="listening on unix socket" address="/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket" 
2017-10-09_23:38:40.15514 time="2017-10-09T23:38:40Z" level=warning msg=exited error="signal: killed" supervisor.args=[bundle exec bin/gitaly-ruby 462 /tmp/gitaly-ruby696108416/socket] supervisor.name=gitaly-ruby 
2017-10-09_23:38:40.15535 time="2017-10-09T23:38:40Z" level=fatal msg="shutting down" error="received signal "terminated"" 
2017-10-09_23:38:40.34508 time="2017-10-09T23:38:40Z" level=info msg="Starting Gitaly" version="Gitaly, version 0.38.0, built 20171005.085339
2017-10-09_23:38:40.34510 " 
2017-10-09_23:38:42.44397 time="2017-10-09T23:38:42Z" level=warning msg="git path not configured. Using default path resolution" resolvedPath="/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git" 
2017-10-09_23:38:42.44981 time="2017-10-09T23:38:42Z" level=info msg="listening on unix socket" address="/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket" 

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Gitlab::Metrics::UnicornSampler: Permission denied - socket(2), stopping

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:38:56.03260 2017/10/09 23:38:56 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory
2017-10-09_23:38:56.03270 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:38:55.985670597 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.046991

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:38:56 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:38:57.84180 2017/10/09 23:38:57 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory
2017-10-09_23:38:57.84183 localhost @ - - [2017-10-09 23:38:57.838499793 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "curl/7.53.0" 0.000775

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:38:57 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "curl/7.53.0"

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:00.14123 2017-10-09T23:39:00.141Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.0.4 with redis options {:host=>"gitlab-ce-redis", :port=>6379, :password=>nil, :namespace=>"resque:gitlab", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-449", :url=>nil}
2017-10-09_23:39:00.27772 2017-10-09T23:39:00.277Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: stuck_ci_jobs_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.27912 2017-10-09T23:39:00.279Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: expire_build_artifacts_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.28200 2017-10-09T23:39:00.281Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: pipeline_schedule_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.28555 2017-10-09T23:39:00.284Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: repository_check_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.33391 2017-10-09T23:39:00.333Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: admin_email_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.33579 2017-10-09T23:39:00.335Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: repository_archive_cache_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.33781 2017-10-09T23:39:00.337Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: import_export_project_cleanup_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.33920 2017-10-09T23:39:00.339Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: requests_profiles_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.34094 2017-10-09T23:39:00.340Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: remove_expired_members_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.34265 2017-10-09T23:39:00.342Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: remove_expired_group_links_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.34406 2017-10-09T23:39:00.343Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: prune_old_events_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.34544 2017-10-09T23:39:00.345Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: trending_projects_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.34735 2017-10-09T23:39:00.347Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: remove_unreferenced_lfs_objects_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.34945 2017-10-09T23:39:00.349Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: stuck_import_jobs_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.35193 2017-10-09T23:39:00.351Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: gitlab_usage_ping_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.35412 2017-10-09T23:39:00.354Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: schedule_update_user_activity_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.35640 2017-10-09T23:39:00.356Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: remove_old_web_hook_logs_worker
2017-10-09_23:39:00.35756 2017-10-09T23:39:00.357Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: stuck_merge_jobs_worker

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Raven 2.5.3 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:05.98562 2017/10/09 23:39:05 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory
2017-10-09_23:39:05.98571 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:39:05.985088651 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.000600

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:39:05 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:06.03714 2017/10/09 23:39:06 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory
2017-10-09_23:39:06.03718 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:39:06.036186491 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.000825

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:39:06 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:11.736355 #430]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:8080 fd=17
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:11.737395 #430]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket fd=18
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:11.759662 #430]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:12.264481 #688]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:12.347996 #691]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:12.84850 adopted new unicorn master 430

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Raven 2.5.3 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set
Started GET "/help" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-10-09 23:39:16 +0000
Started GET "/help" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-10-09 23:39:16 +0000

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:39:16 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:39:17 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:17.03229 2017/10/09 23:39:17 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 1s: context canceled
2017-10-09_23:39:17.03242 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:39:15.985524184 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 1.046852
2017-10-09_23:39:17.03377 2017/10/09 23:39:17 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 1s: context canceled
2017-10-09_23:39:17.03392 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:39:15.98632 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 1.047559

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:22.04907 2017-10-09T23:39:22.048Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]
2017-10-09_23:39:22.04911 2017-10-09T23:39:22.049Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2017-10-09_23:39:22.04917 2017-10-09T23:39:22.049Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2017-10-09_23:39:22.05095 2017-10-09T23:39:22.050Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:39:26 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:26.99305 2017/10/09 23:39:26 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 1s: context canceled

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2017:23:39:26 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:27.03385 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:39:26.040828012 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.992052
2017-10-09_23:39:27.03791 2017/10/09 23:39:27 error: GET "/help": badgateway: failed after 1s: context canceled
2017-10-09_23:39:27.03806 172.17.0.3:80 @ - - [2017-10-09 23:39:26.040759024 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 502 2916 "" "Go-http-client/1.1" 0.997263
SIGTERM signal received, try to gracefully shutdown all services...

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitaly/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:29.25293 time="2017-10-09T23:39:29Z" level=warning msg=exited error="signal: killed" supervisor.args=[bundle exec bin/gitaly-ruby 590 /tmp/gitaly-ruby174846663/socket] supervisor.name=gitaly-ruby 
2017-10-09_23:39:29.25321 time="2017-10-09T23:39:29Z" level=fatal msg="shutting down" error="received signal "terminated"" 
ok: down: gitaly: 0s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Processing by HelpController#index as HTML
Processing by HelpController#index as HTML
ok: down: gitlab-workhorse: 1s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/logrotate/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:30.14036 Received TERM from runit, sending to process group (-PID)
ok: down: logrotate: 0s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Completed 200 OK in 893ms (Views: 837.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/help","format":"html","controller":"HelpController","action":"index","status":200,"duration":902.35,"view":837.09,"db":0.0,"time":"2017-10-09T23:39:29.985Z","params":{},"remote_ip":"172.17.0.1","user_id":null,"username":null}

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/help" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-10-09 23:39:30 +0000
Completed 200 OK in 963ms (Views: 893.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Processing by HelpController#index as HTML

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/help","format":"html","controller":"HelpController","action":"index","status":200,"duration":974.34,"view":893.21,"db":0.0,"time":"2017-10-09T23:39:29.972Z","params":{},"remote_ip":"172.17.0.1","user_id":null,"username":null}

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/help" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-10-09 23:39:30 +0000
Processing by HelpController#index as HTML
ok: down: nginx: 0s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:30.98500 2017-10-09T23:39:30.984Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Shutting down
2017-10-09_23:39:30.98516 2017-10-09T23:39:30.985Z 449 TID-os7h8efos INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2017-10-09_23:39:30.98647 2017-10-09T23:39:30.985Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Terminating quiet workers
2017-10-09_23:39:30.98990 2017-10-09T23:39:30.988Z 449 TID-os7h7dfhw INFO: Scheduler exiting...

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Completed 200 OK in 297ms (Views: 285.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/help","format":"html","controller":"HelpController","action":"index","status":200,"duration":298.28,"view":285.88,"db":0.0,"time":"2017-10-09T23:39:30.941Z","params":{},"remote_ip":"172.17.0.1","user_id":null,"username":null}

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Completed 200 OK in 307ms (Views: 288.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log <==
{"method":"GET","path":"/help","format":"html","controller":"HelpController","action":"index","status":200,"duration":308.33,"view":288.37,"db":0.0,"time":"2017-10-09T23:39:30.963Z","params":{},"remote_ip":"172.17.0.1","user_id":null,"username":null}

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:31.48927 2017-10-09T23:39:31.489Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
2017-10-09_23:39:32.49155 2017-10-09T23:39:32.491Z 449 TID-os7jwj948 INFO: Bye!
ok: down: sidekiq: 0s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:32.66837 Received signal 15; terminating.
ok: down: sshd: 1s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2017-10-09_23:39:33.08843 Received TERM from runit, sending to process group (-PID)
2017-10-09_23:39:33.09022 Terminated
2017-10-09_23:39:33.09035 forwarding TERM to unicorn master 430
2017-10-09_23:39:33.09049 forwarding CONT to unicorn master 430
2017-10-09_23:39:33.09056 wrapper for unicorn master 430 exiting

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:33.191138 #430]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 688 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:33.191330 #430]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 691 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2017-10-09T23:39:33.191576 #430]  INFO -- : master complete
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/daemon.rb:46:in `join': Target thread must not be current thread (ThreadError)
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/daemon.rb:46:in `block in stop'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/daemon.rb:39:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/daemon.rb:39:in `stop'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/base_sampler.rb:19:in `rescue in safe_sample'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/base_sampler.rb:16:in `safe_sample'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/base_sampler.rb:52:in `start_working'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/daemon.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in start'
ok: down: unicorn: 0s, normally up
```

Comment: What OpenShift environment are you using? You cannot deploy GitLab to OpenShift Online as unless they changed their images, they require the ability to be started as root.

Comment: I've updated to specify my installation.

Comment: Are you able to install any other more simple applications to OpenShift?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins installs and works fine from the default template