# Gitlab Error 502 when trying to pull/push

Tags: git, nginx, debian, gitlab

So this is a rather long story, hope you stick with me.

Debian 8. Once I had a gitlab-ce installation using a non-bundled nginx server (subdomain) which I uninstalled using "gitlab-ctl uninstall".

Then a week ago I installed gitlab-ee without checking again or changing any configs - first it looked fine and was still reachable from the subdomain.
Then I wanted to push a project - Error 502, oh yeah Im using cloudflare (port 22 blocked) - switched to http, tried again - Error 502. F*ck.

2 hours google and 20 potential stackoverflow/gitlab_issue fixes later I had even worse errors where nothing would work at all and I am getting tired.
So I rewinded everthing and hope for help.

Nginx main git config:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen *:8080;
  server_name [domain].me
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  # Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
  passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

  # Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
  passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

  # Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
  # prevent permission issues
  passenger_user git;
  passenger_group git;

  # Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 1;

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$ {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/builds/download {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /ci/api/v1/builds/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /api/v4/jobs/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }


  # For protocol upgrades from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 we need to provide Host header if its missing
  if ($http_host = "") {
  # use one of values defined in server_name
    set $http_host_with_default "git.example.com";
  }

  if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
  }

  location @gitlab-workhorse {

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    # Do not buffer Git HTTP responses
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host_with_default;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;

    ## The following settings only work with NGINX 1.7.11 or newer
    #
    ## Pass chunked request bodies to gitlab-workhorse as-is
    # proxy_request_buffering off;
    # proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

  ## Enable gzip compression as per rails guide:
  ## http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression
  ## WARNING: If you are using relative urls remove the block below
  ## See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
  ## other files that need to be changed for relative url support
  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

Nginx subdomain git config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.[domain].me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
    } 
}
```

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb modified lines:

```
external_url 'http://[domain].me:8080'

web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']

gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = 'http://[domain].me:8080'

unicorn['enable'] = false

nginx['enable'] = false
```

gitlab-ctl tail error:

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
>       2017-10-12_12:02:05.54645 2017/10/12 14:02:05 error: GET "": badgateway: failed after 0s: dial unix
>   /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such
>   file or directory

Maybe someone could help me... I am losing confidence in humanity.
And dont dare telling me to just reconfigure, restart, reload or reinstall. Ive done all of this at least twice.

Edit*: Also some gitlab Dev (@ibaum) told me this: "It looks like you're trying to use passenger instead of unicorn. And based on the logs, it looks like that is the cause of your issues. This isn't really a configuration we support."
I have no cluse what he is saying, and what both of these things do. I just wanna get it running.

Comment: Why don't you use Gitlab Docker images? It is easiest to setup https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html

Comment: @TarunLalwani - i get a similar error using the docker image - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667142/gitlab-ce-on-openshift-origin-3-7-0-alpha-fedora-26-fails-to-start

Comment: using Docker on Ubuntu 16 now, works perfectly so far thanks for the idea.... now I'm just getting cancer setting up my mailserver again. Even though I basically ignored the problem but whatever